# Change line type on specified interval in R

Tags: r, plot

Using the `plot()` function, is it possible to change the line type over a certain interval (e.g. from `x=1` to `x=2`) and leave the rest of the plot as another line type?

I know I could use `lines()` multiple times for the same effect, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way.

Comment: I don't think so: try `?segments` ?

Comment: You can do similar things with points and with type="b" which has points and lines. Here is an example: `plot(0:20, seq(0, 10, by=.5) , type="b", col=ifelse(0:20 %in% 0:2,  "black", "red"), pch=ifelse(0:20 %in% 0:2,  2, 6))`.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I just spent some time failing with lty, but wanted to let the OP know that something that may convey the same information is possible, if less desirable.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi : it would be interesting to post to `r-devel@r-project.org` and see if anyone can explain how one is supposed to interpret that statement in the docs about recycling (which on the face of it seems to be false, but ... ????)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using ggplot instead?

```
data <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20),20))
names(data) <- "series"

library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(cbind(Index=1:nrow(data),data))
data$Col <- data$Index < 8 & data$Index > 3
ggplot(data, aes(x=Index,y=series,color=factor(Col))) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=1),size=1) +
  guides(colour=F)
```

[image]